# How to pass a list as input to asp classic stored procedure call

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I am trying to pass a string list to a stored procedure call in asp classic

```
objCmd.Parameters.Append(objCmd.CreateParameter("@UniNumberList", adVarChar, adParamInput,strUnitNumberList))
```

Where as in SQL stored proc I have a variable which accepts input

```
@UniNumberList as varchar(max)
```

How should I pass maximum size of the parameter while adding parameter in ASP classic ?

**Error : Provider error '8002000a'**

Out of present range.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Workaround I have made by assigning parameter size as 8000 at both places in asp code and SQL stored Proc, is there any alternate solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You should install SQL Server Native client to get it to understand `varchar(max)`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130978.aspx

A better solution might be upgrading to ASP.net. ASP.classic is prehistoric.